# Overriding New button on Opportunity in Lightning page

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I have created a button - 'New' on opportunity. User is clicking it from account ->Opportunity Related list to create a new opportunity. My Component and Controller is like this ->

```
-----------------Component-----------------
    <aura:component Controller="New_Opportunity" implements="lightning:actionOverride,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
        <aura:handler name="init" value="this" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
        <aura:attribute name="parentRecordId" type="String"/>
        <aura:attribute name="url" type="String" default="URL"/>
        <!--  <aura:attribute name="AccountName" type="String" default=""/> -->

        <aura:if isTrue="{!or(v.url == null, v.url == '')}">
            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="font-size: 1.25em; font-weight: bold;">
                <h2>Opportunity can not be created from here</h2>
            </div>
        </aura:if>
    </aura:component>
-----------------Controller-----------------
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log("I am 12");
//More code goes here//
```

//helper method executing apex controller method.//
        }
    })
Issue is when I am clicking the New button, doInit is executing twice (console log is printing "I am 12" twice and apex controller printing debugs twice) and therefore any code inside it is executing 2 times. I have tried everything but nothing is working.[image: Overriding New button to create Opportunity from Account]

Comment: try to put `doinit` at the end of attributes

Comment: @Sarvesh - It won't help because whole of the Lightning component is executing twice. Don't know why.

Comment: I am not sure why a component loading twice, but there is a workaround to fix this, create a boolean attribute, set as true on the first load and check the value of the attribute.

Comment: @Sarvesh - Have tried that. Because its executing twice, any variable declared gets reset both the time.